# count the line number of a file, when passing file data to a string tokenizer in java

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, token

If I want to copy the content of a text file using a string tokenizer let's say like this:

```
StringTokenizer strk = new StringTokenizer(new String(buffer), Constant.DELIMS,true);
```

And then I want to browse the string tokenizer but also keep count in a variable of how many lines I passed from the initial file:(by this I mean count how many tokens that represent a newline character)

```
nr_lines=0;
endline="\n";
while (strk.hasMoreTokens()) {
       String word = strk.nextToken(); 
       if (word.equals(endline)) nr_lines++;  
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work right. Am I making the comparison with a wrong delimiter(\n). I also tried with \r. But it returns larger numbers than it should, like nr_lines would increment when it shouldn't. Could you please help me out. Also if you have another idea of how I could keep track of the line number after transferring the content of a file to a string tokenizer, it would be most welcomed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `Scanner` instead. While it isn't as useful for returning `Object`s, it has the `nextLine` method, which you can then parse through using `StringTokenizer`.

Like this:

```
New Scanner
New StringTokenizer

Get next line from Scanner
  Count the line
  Re-initialize StringTokenizer with the newly read line from Scanner
```

Comment: I meant to take that out, it won't do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

If your are on a windows machine the new line character is expressed in text files as a carriage return "\r" followed by a line feed "\n" so newLine = "\r\n", and since you are using the StringTokenizer constructor that takes a delimiter and a boolean variable be sure of your delimiter character.

Comment: Then wouldn't it be enough if I just looked for \n? or \n could appear in a text file also with another use? The Constant.DELIMS I am using as a parameter is: public final static String DELIMS = ".,!?;: \r\t\n\"*()/][\\`'";